# Login takes long time when there's no internet

Tags: login, network-manager

I have noticed, after I upgraded to 14.04, that when I have a poor Wifi connection or the network is disabled from the the login screen, the resulting login can take over two minutes.

If I have a good connection then it's a few seconds.

I have disabled any Startup stuff that might need network, but even so just getting from login to desktop shouldn't stop to wait for the internet.

Any thoughts?

sudo tail /var/log/syslog login lagging:

```
    Apr 30 16:32:38 cho kernel: [  241.230119]  [<ffffffff810c7bc8>] ? __call_rcu_nocb_enqueue+0xa8/0xc0
Apr 30 16:32:38 cho kernel: [  241.230126]  [<ffffffff811ca091>] user_path_at+0x11/0x20
Apr 30 16:32:38 cho kernel: [  241.230136]  [<ffffffff811be2b0>] vfs_fstatat+0x50/0xa0
Apr 30 16:32:38 cho kernel: [  241.230143]  [<ffffffff8109d76b>] ? account_user_time+0x8b/0xa0
Apr 30 16:32:38 cho kernel: [  241.230151]  [<ffffffff811be74f>] SYSC_newstat+0x1f/0x40
Apr 30 16:32:38 cho kernel: [  241.230163]  [<ffffffff81020d35>] ? syscall_trace_enter+0x145/0x250
Apr 30 16:32:38 cho kernel: [  241.230173]  [<ffffffff817265dc>] ? tracesys+0x7e/0xe6
Apr 30 16:32:38 cho kernel: [  241.230181]  [<ffffffff811be99e>] SyS_newstat+0xe/0x10
Apr 30 16:32:38 cho kernel: [  241.230187]  [<ffffffff8172663f>] tracesys+0xe1/0xe6
Apr 30 16:34:31 cho sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/xxxx is already mounted
```

sudo tail /var/log/syslog login good

```
Apr 30 16:38:55 cho kernel: [   40.810360] type=1400 audit(1398872335.618:72): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=3016 comm="apparmor_parser"
Apr 30 16:38:55 cho colord: Profile added: HP-Officejet-Pro-8500-A910-Gray..
Apr 30 16:38:55 cho colord: Profile added: HP-Officejet-Pro-8500-A910-RGB..
Apr 30 16:38:55 cho colord: Device added: cups-HP-Officejet-Pro-8500-A910
Apr 30 16:38:58 cho ntpd_intres[1437]: parent died before we finished, exiting
Apr 30 16:38:58 cho bluetoothd[571]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Apr 30 16:38:58 cho bluetoothd[571]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Apr 30 16:38:58 cho bluetoothd[571]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Apr 30 16:38:58 cho bluetoothd[571]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.38 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Apr 30 16:39:02 cho sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/xxxxx is already mounted
```

cat ~/.xsession-errors  login lagging

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
```

cat ~/.xsession-errors  login good

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
```

Comment: Add the output of `sudo tail /var/log/syslog` and `cat ~/.xsession-errors` when the logging lags and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Laptop ethernet?  Your graphical boot animation/logger (Plymouth) is waiting for your hardline net connections so you can mount any network file systems.  To remedy your problem, you can keep either change the timeout for Plymouth, or you can specifiy your ethernet adapter to not be configured by NetworkManager -- try appending 'auto eth0 inet dhcp' to your /etc/network/interfaces file.